# Apache Spark: List all the Sparks job running on the cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, cluster-computing, bigdata

Is there a command that list all the spark jobs running on the cluster? 
I am new to this technology and we have multiple users running spark-submit jobs on a aws cluster. Is there a way to list all the spark jobs running?
Thank you!

Comment: The Spark History Server UI should already list all of them. If you are running a YARN cluster, then the resource manager UI also lists them. Haven't tried Mesos, but I'm sure that does it as well

Answer (score 0):

Use [Spark REST API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api). It can be invoked from active Spark Web UI or from History Server. Of course, as cricket_007 said, you can also list jobs in UI. These UIs and REST services are running in all cluster types